# How many people arrived in T/4

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution, queueing-theory

The number of people arrived during a time interval follows Poisson distribution. Suppose there is only one customer arriving in the shop during time $T$, how many people arrive during time $T/4$?

I think the time between two arrivers follows exponential distribution $\exp(1/T)$, so the expectation of "time between two arrivers" is $1/T$. Then during $T/4$ time, there are $T^2/4$ customers arrived. Am I correct?

Comment: Is the $T/4$ time period a subset of the $T$ time period in which only one customer arrives?  If so, the answer can only be $0$ or $1$, and is $1$ with probability $\frac14$ so has expectation $\frac14$.   Or is is that the number arriving in a period of  time $T$ is Poisson distributed with expectation $1$? So the number arriving in a period of  time $T/4$ is Poisson distributed with expectation $\frac14$.

Comment: Hi @Henry, thanks for your reply! I am not sure about the independence..maybe it's just another independent T/4? but for your latter statement, why is a "Poisson distributed with expectation 1/4"?

Comment: A Poisson process with rate $\lambda$ has an expectation of $\lambda t$ events in time period $t$.  Here you seem to have $\lambda= \frac1T$ so when $t=T$ you have an expectation of $1$ and when $t=\frac T4$ an expectation of $\frac14$